# differentiable and uniform continuity of f and F

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Given $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. define new function: $F(x) =\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ for $x\neq a$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $F$ is uniformly continuous in some punctured neighborhood around $a$.

I was playing around with the definitions of both and I think the backward direction is easier but I'm having trouble with the absolute values which come with the definitions.

I was thinking of defining $F(x)$ to be $f'(a)$ since it is a limit definition of the derivative. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Do you have trouble with one implication or both?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Comment: P.S. I think we should also assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Adayah If what OP wants to prove is true, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I was trying to say that the $(\implies)$ implication does not hold without that assumption: take $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$ so $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ but not continuous elsewhere hence $F$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The forward direction is false.

Let $f(x) = x^2 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but
$F(x) = x 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$, while continuous at $x=0$ is not continuous 
at $x$ for any $x \neq 0$.

The reverse direction is straightforward:

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and define $F(a) = f'(a)$. Then let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that
$|f(x)-f(a) -f'(x) (x-a)| \le {1 \over 2} \epsilon |x-a|$ for all $x \in B(a, \delta)$.

Now suppose $x,y \in B(a,\delta)$, with $\delta \le 1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |f(x)-f(a) -f'(x) (x-a)|+ |f(y)-f(a) -f'(y) (y-a)| \le \epsilon $, and
so $F$ is

Suppose $F$ is uniformly continuous in $B(a,r)\setminus \{x\}$. Since $F$ is
uniformly continuous, we can uniquely extend the domain of $F$ to include $a$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that $|F(x)-F(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $|x-a| < \delta$. Then, for $0<|x-a|< \delta$, we have
$| { f(x)-f(a) \over x-a} -F(a)| < \epsilon$. Hence
$\lim_{x \to a} {f(x)-f(a) \over x-a} =F(a)$ and so $f$ is differentiable at $x$
with derivative $F(a)$.